# light bleed on objects in eevee render engine on Blender 2.81a

Tags: light, lighting

in 2.80 there is an exponent and bleed bias slider on the shadow option on lights to get around the light bleed, but in 2.81a there isn't/missing and I'm having trouble on how to avoid/fix lights bleeding into the interior of objects, any ideas?

Comment: This was intentionally removed here: https://developer.blender.org/D5659 As far as I understand, the developers felt that the new shadow model deals well with light leak on its own. But don't quote me on this reasoning.